# How to remove wall adhesive from the wall that has a wall paper?

Tags: adhesive, wallpaper

I have a wall adhesive hook which I initially though would be easy to pull out. But it was not. I made some damage to wallpaper also because of my forceful, stupid action. Is there any chemical to remove this adhesive and fix the wall paper also?

[image]

Comment: You won't find one chemical that will remove the glue and fix the wall paper. Makes me think of the old cartoons where Donald dips his brush into the paint can then paints a colored pattern onto the wall. Can't find the cartoon on YT, so maybe it's another cartoon character...

Answer (score 2):

As far as removing, many adhesives soften, or become less "sticky" with some heat.  Have you tried using a heat gun or blow dryer?  Be careful handling the hook after applying the heat—use gloves.

As to repair, it really depends what you're left with once the hook is removed.

Comment: I will try with a blow dryer.